# Programming without installing or maintaining servers

Tags: development-environment

**== Problem ==**

Mukesh is a competent PHP and ASP programmer-type who does mostly web development. He wishes to branch out into projects based on different programming languages.

The problem is, the sysadmin over Mukesh is really adamant about not allowing setup or install *anything* except the absolute bare minimum on local machines. Moreover, Mukesh is stuck with a windows-based machine.

Mukesh will have an ssh terminal, and a text editor, and perhaps a local install of Git. That's it.

**== Rationale ==**

Mukesh wants to get a feel for what full-stack development is like in a bunch of different environments, but he is not able to install programs and has a limited budget to work with.

Mukesh just wants to brainstorm all the different ways he can gain full-stack programming experiences in a lot of different environments while still just having nothing more than a text editor and SSH access.

**== Question ==**

How many products, services, or strategies are out there that will allow Mukesh to routinely develop in a bunch of different environments, where he is fairly locked down on what he can install on his own machine, and does not have many alternatives (e.g., Mukesh does not own a computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get permission to install a VM product.  It will allow you to run numerous operating systems in a virtual machine, separate from the host OS.  For example, VirtualBox (free) ( https://www.virtualbox.org ) will allow you to host any number of Linux, UNIX, Windows, DOS even, and a large number of experimental operating systems.

The only real limitation on running them is the amount of memory you have, CPU horsepower, and disk space to hold the VM images.  On a modern system with a lot of RAM and multiple CPUs and/or cores, you can even run several different VM's simultaneously.

You should also know that most of the time graphics hardware acceleration isn't present, so you can run video games, CAD, or other graphics intensive software inside the VM, but it usually does not perform very well.  For just about any other purpose (like programming, testing compilers, etc.) it is quite useful.

You could probably host all of it on an external drive or even a USB key if you aren't allowed to put anything on the system itself.

Another option would be to use a hosting provider that allows shell access for a target platform you don't have available to you locally.  Most I have seen cost a small amount of money, but there are probably free providers as well.